# How to enable async.mapLimit to work with TypeScript async / await

Tags: typescript, async-await, async.js

Is it possible to use the [Async NPM module](https://caolan.github.io/async/) to work with `async`/`await` in TypeScript 2.2x?

**Goal:** 
Create a web scraper that spins up 10 parallel HTTP requests using Async's [mapLimit function](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#mapLimit).

An example of the wrapped HTTP function would be as follows:

```
async callUniRest(url: string): Promise<number> {
  return new Promise<number>(resolve => {
    unirest.get(url)
      .end((response: any) => {
          resolve(cheerio.load(response.body);
      });
    });
}
```

**Problem:**

When I run:

```
const myList: string[] = ['http...', 'http...', 'http...', 'http...']
async.mapLimit(myList, 10, callUniRest, function(err: any, results: any {
  console.log(results);
})
```

the callback only gets called after the first element finishes.

**Question:** 
How do I enable `async.mapLimit` to work with multiple calls?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it possible to use the 'async' npm module to work with async / await in Typescript

Yes.

I found that `mapLimit` was only calling the iterator for the first set. This was because I was transpiling from TypeScript. If I used native async/await with JS then it worked. This is because, quoted from the [async docs for AsyncFunction](http://caolan.github.io/async/v3/global.html):

> due to JavaScript limitations, we can only detect native async functions and not transpilied implementations.

So if you wrap your iterator with `asyncify` from the async library then you can return from inside your iterator and not use a callback:

> If you are using async functions through a transpiler (e.g. Babel), you must still wrap the function with asyncify, because the async function will be compiled to an ordinary function that returns a promise.

Here's a somewhat contrived TypeScript example that demonstrates how to do this. Note: if you remove the `asyncify` call it won't work:

```
import { asyncify, mapLimit } from "async";

const listOfThings = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".split("");

const convertToUppercase = async () =>
  await mapLimit<string, string[]>(
    listOfThings,
    5,
    asyncify(async letter => letter.toUpperCase())
  );

const init = async () => {
  const uppered = await convertToUppercase();

  console.log("done", uppered);
};

init();
```

Answer (score 0):

No. The `async` module provides utilities and abstractions for folks who cannot or would not use Promises. They don't mix.

<s>Not to mention, by the time you have `myList`, all of the requests were already sent.</s>

`async.mapLimit` only works with functions that accept a callback, and not with ones that return a Promise.

What you might want is to use Bluebird's [`Promise.map()` with the `concurrency` operator](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.map.html)

Comment: i guess a better question would be how to enable concurrency using async await

Comment: @JackMurphy With a counter/stack. There's no built-in way. Hence my suggestion to use Bluebird.